# Can Javascript do some explicit/manual memory operation?

Tags: javascript

In C, if I don't need some specific memory region, I could delete such memory region manually. I am wondering in Javascript, I can do the same thing.

Or Is there some virtual memory interface I can leverage.

Comment: Provide a real example for this in JS please.

Comment: For some huge memory operation, I would like to free some. Chrome only have 32 bit, it is hard to use JS to do huge memory operation without it.

Comment: if you stop using something (don't have access to an object from a current/global scope) - it's freed automatically.

Comment: True but unfortunatelly the garbage collerctor is not called immediately.

Comment: @Matúš Dúbrava: it's actually "fortunately" :-)

Comment: Depends. That way you would at least have some knowledge when the GC is called. Now you don't and js calls it to it's liking. Which means it can call it immediately as well (e.g. when you run out of memory, as soon as all the references to some variable are cut the GC is called).

Answer (score 1):

No. Nor should you "need" to. Javascript manages the memory, and does not expose its implementation.

(This becomes very, very useful for things like garbage collection, particularly the stop-and-copy variety.)

As soon as you have no references to an object, Javascript can deallocate that memory. Implementations vary in how often they actually deallocate the memory (aka garbage collect), but if you ever run out of memory, they will certainly do it then.

```
var a = {a: 1};
// can't garbage collect {a: 1}
a = null;
// can garbage collect {a: 1}

var b = {b: 1};
// can't garbage collect {b: 1}
var c = b;
// can't garbage collect {b: 1}
b = null;
// can't garbage collect {b: 1}
c = null;
// can garbage collect {b: 1}
```

---

Perhaps you should ask a higher-level question, about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not allow you to manually clear the memory. And you should not be concerned about it either when it does it for you.

On the other hand javascript clears used memory when there are no references to that memory. All you can do is to cut those references. Let's say:

```
var x = some object;

x = null;
```